# Java Read & Display Template Document, Fill with GUI Variables than take Print Output

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am confused a bit. I want make & display simple editable and printable some Information Slip module and add to my Java desktop application. I am doing first time something like that and need any advice because of this.

I draw a sample Information Slip in Power Point just for an example. Can be seen at below;

[image: Sample Information Slip]

Sender Informations info coming from some GUI Element. Also Service Name, Brand, Model, SeriNo, Sending Date and Product Problem infos.

**Question 1:** Should i create this Template in Java and fill it? If it yes; which classes can be helpful for this operation?

**Question 2:** If No; Which model should using for create Template (Excel, Word, PowerPoint) and Apache POI can be helpful for reading, displaying and editing template in JAVA Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `itext` library for creating PDF file because has very detailed rendering functions for PDF creation. When user click the button i write a template and fill the blank cells from DB everytime.

Than i use `Icepdf` library for show to user and taking output of the created pdf file.

But Icepdf has some character encoding problem i think. When PDf created and callled by `Icepdf` one of Turkish character looks as square. Turkish characters can be seen at this [link](http://turkish.typeit.org/). All characters rendered succesfully but eighth character at the link is not.

When i go to filepath of created pdf file (created by `itext` library) and open it manually with Adobe Acrobat Reader all characters showing correctly. But if programaticly `Icepdf` open the file and show to user, eighth character at the link looks as square.

I need change character encoding of Icepdf but i can't yet. Reading many articles about character and `Font` encoding of `Icepdf` but i have not yet succeeded. If i solve this character problem my application ready to deploy.

**-- Character Issue Solved --**

I solved the special character issue when PDF file shown on screen via `IcePdf`

If you are not using `IcePdf Pro` (which support all asian languages etc.) you need embed the third party `Font` file (which tested all your language's special character support font) when you create PDF file with `iText`. And `IcePdf` can use embedded `Font` file for render and show the document accurately now.

For how embed the `Font` files to the PDF with `iText` you should check my last question and answer about that;

[Icepdf special character rendering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104669/icepdf-special-character-rendering-issue)